# Delete a whole element in a XML-File

Tags: c#, xml

As i said in the Title:
I want to Delete a whole element in a Xml-File with c# if the value of an attribute of this element is preRequisite.

XML File :

```
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite"></dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install"></dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

current Code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))//filepath is just a normal Path
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name == "dependentAssembly" && reader.GetAttribute("dependencyType") != "preRequisite")
        {
        //here shall it delete the Element "dependency"
        }
    }
}
```

At the place where i set the command it shall delete the Element "dependency"

i tried many things but i dont get how i shall delete this Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var xml = XElement.Load(File.OpenRead(@"XmlLocation"));

var elementsToDelete =
    xml.Descendants("dependentAssembly")
       .Where(x => x.Attribute("dependencyType") != null && 
                   x.Attribute("dependencyType").Value != "preRequisite");

foreach (var xElement in elementsToDelete)
{
    xElement.Remove();
}
```

Comment: This might give a nullref exception when the element doesnt have an attribute called dependencyType

Comment: shall element be the file?

Comment: @CSharpie Thanks, i added a nullity check.

Comment: @CSharpie no worries it does always have depndencyType in it :)

Comment: @Gentle i added the xml variable. For testing purposes i just read it from a file.

Comment: @Gentle you can also use `XElement.Parse` if you already have the XML string in memory.

Comment: @YuvaLItzchakov  sry but i dont understand what is XElement it does not exist in my context ... did i forgot a namespace? :/

Comment: You need to reference `System.Xml.Linq` like this: `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: `x.Name == "dependentAssembly"` is a bad idea. why not just `xml.Descendants("dependentAssembly")` ?

Comment: Hmm, why is it a bad idea? I didn't see that overload for `Descendants` :)

Comment: because you are iterating over all elements.. instead you can use more proper overloead of `Descendants` which does the filtering for you. also it won't work if the element has a namespace.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i did that but it  does not delete them... it lets them there ... i watched in the XML file and its still there...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i went into it with breakpoints and it does never go into xElement.Remove();

Comment: @Gentle Are you sure you loaded the XML correctly? see if elementsToRemove has any elements inside it. You do have to save the XML again after you're done with it using `xml.Save`. I tested this and it works.

Comment: sorry i made some mistakes ^^ Thanks for your help